# Does Google provide hosting servers means like vps or dedicated servers?

Tags: hosting, vps, google, dedicated-server

I want to make it sure does google provide hosting servers like virtual private servers or dedicated besides free hosting that is available from sites.google.com

Does google have something like rackspace, linode or do they only provide free hosting for simple websites?

Comment: For the future, this is the sort of question which should be asked of *Google* directly -- It's a [shopping question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) on its best day, and while interesting (I'd never heard of Google Cloud) it's not really on-topic...

Comment: Well I think its a top question, because Google call their hosting product "Compute Engine", a term that they have recently coined which does not related to hosting, VPS, or dedicated server. I have 25 years industry experience and even with that I could not determine which of Google services - if any - related to site and service hosting. I think its as much a technical question as a shopping question. And interesting to note that you didnt post the link to where one might ask Google such a question.

Comment: @ekerner thank you for understand what exactly I was feeling and searching for at the time of posting this question. And indeed, where should a person ask this from google.

Comment: @voretaq7, Google ain't Apple. There's not a single way to talk to a single human at Google.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it does: http://cloud.google.com/

Specifically: http://cloud.google.com/pricing/compute-engine.html

Comment: Google's VM allows you to set vCPUs not real cpus. So I guess that's not dedicated cpus and your cpu performance will be affected by the hoster beside you?